# result.success Failing in ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, json

My code run's through fine but fails when it gets to the success call. On the ajax section "if (result.success){" it shows an error in the browsers sources tab with result being null.

**Login Page**:

```
<form id="login_form_header">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="sc_ajax_callback" />
    <input type="hidden" name="func" value="sc_login" />

    Email:
    <input type="text" name="username" />

    Password:
    <input type="password" name="password"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</form>
<script>
$("#login_form_header").submit(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/connect.php',
        data: $('#login_form_header').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
            if (result.success){
                window.location = "my-dashboard/";
                return false;
            };
        },
        error: function(e){console.log("Could not retrieve login information")}
    });

    return false;
});
</script>
```

**Connect Page**:

```
<?php 

    mysql_connect("localhost", "%user%", "%pass%") or die(mysql_error()); // Connect to database server(localhost) with username and password.
    mysql_select_db("%db%") or die(mysql_error()); // Select registration database.
    # Make sure form data was passed to the script
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) AND isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){

    # Define Variables
    $active_var = "1";
    $given_username = mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $given_password = dosomethingtopass;
    $matched_username = "";
    $matched_password = "";

     # See if there is matching info in the database
    $sql = 'SELECT username, password, active FROM %table% WHERE username="'.$given_username.'" AND password="'.$given_password.'" AND active="'.$active_var.'"'; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if($given_password == $row['password']){
        $matched_username = $row['username'];
        $matched_password = $row['password'];
        }
    };

    # If there was a match 
    if($matched_username != "" && $matched_password != ""){
        #If there is only one result returned
        echo json_encode(array("$matched_password"));
        $session_sql = 'SELECT id, username, password, last_login FROM %table% WHERE username="'.$matched_username.'" AND password="'.$matched_password.'"';
        $session_result = mysql_query($session_sql);
        while($returned_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($session_result)){
            if($matched_password == $returned_row['password']){ 


            $_SESSION['id'] = $returned_row['id'];
            //$_SESSION['last_login'] = $returned_row['last_login'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $returned_row['username'];
                }
             }

            $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $update_sql = "UPDATE %table% SET last_login='".$date."'";
            mysql_query($update_sql);

        echo json_encode(array("success"=>"user logged in", "session"=>$_SESSION));
        }
    }

?>
```

Also the update_sql is updating every row in my table kinda odd. Not sure where I am going wrong any help?

EDIT:

Updated

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/connect.php',
        data: $('#login_form_header').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){

                window.location = "my-dashboard/";

            };
        },
        error: function(e){console.log("Could not retrieve login information")}
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
success: function(result){
            if (result.success){
                window.location = "my-dashboard/";
                return false;
            };
```

change to

```
success: function(result){                    
                    window.location = "my-dashboard/";                     
                }
```

`result` here is te data sent by the server, not an object.

---

> **Also the update_sql is updating every row in my table kinda odd**

It is because there is no `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` query.

*From the documentation:*

> The WHERE clause, if given, specifies the conditions that identify which rows to update. With no WHERE clause, **all rows are updated.**

More info [**here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

**EDIT after update**

you have an extra `};`.

change

```
success: function(result){

                window.location = "my-dashboard/";

            };
        },
```

to

```
success: function(result){

                window.location = "my-dashboard/";


        },
```

A few point worth to mention:

- Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.
- mysql_* functions are being deprecated. Use PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

`success: function(result){
  window.location = "my-dashboard/";
}`

because this function called on success result.
And first param is data from server answer. This is no object.
You can find details there: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Updated the question, it kinda works but now I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; " in the console.